# Why is a class allowed to have a static member of itself, but not a non-static member?

Tags: c++, object, static-members

```
class base {
public:
    base a;
};
```

It gives compilation error.

```
class base {
public:
    static base a;
};
```

whereas this code does not give compilation error

Comment: struct a { static a b; } a::b;

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb You just gave me a headache o_O

Comment: Yo dog, I heard you like classes...

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Because `static` class members are not stored in the class instance, that's why a `static` would work.

Storing an object inside another object of the same type would break the runtime - infinite size, right?

What would `sizeof` return? The size of the object needs to be known by the compiler, but since it contains an object of the same type, it doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 6):

I'm guessing the error is something like

> field ‘a’ has incomplete type

This is because when not static, the class `A` is not fully defined until the closing brace. Static member variables, on the other hand, need a separate definition step after the class is fully defined, which is why they work.

Search for the difference between *declaration* and *definition* for more thorough explanations.

Comment: Couldn't the compiler sort of "set a reminder" for itself to "add" that later? What's the limitation?

Comment: @AssafLevy What would the size of the object be.  `Base` contains a `Base`, which contains a `Base`...

Comment: @JamesKanze: Sort of two mirrors facing eachother.. Got it, thanks!