# C++ LinkedList using template

Tags: c++, templates, generics

I want to make my own linkedlist implementatin in c++ using templates. However, I run into several compiler errors. Here is the code:

```
template <class T>
class Node{
T datum;
Node _next = NULL;
 public:
 Node(T datum)
{
    this->datum = datum;
}
 void setNext(Node next)
 {
     _next = next;
 }
 Node getNext()
 {
     return _next;
 }
 T getDatum()
 {
     return datum;
 }          
};
template <class T>
class LinkedList{
Node<T> *node;
Node<T> *currPtr;
Node<T> *next_pointer;
int size;
public:
LinkedList(T datum)
  {
      node = new Node<T>(datum);
      currPtr = node;  //assignment between two pointers.
      size = 1;
  }
void add(T datum)
 {
   Node<T> *temp = new Node<T>(datum);
   (*currPtr).setNext((*temp));
   currPtr = temp;       
   size++;
 }
T next()
{
   next_pointer = node;
   T data = (*next_pointer).getDatum();
   next_pointer = (*next_pointer).getNext();
   return data;
}
int getSize()
{
   return size;
}   
};
```

when I try to instantiate this class, I got the following errors:

```
LinkedList.cpp: In instantiation of `Node<int>':
LinkedList.cpp:35:   instantiated from `LinkedList<T>::LinkedList(T) [with T = int]'
LinkedList.cpp:60:   instantiated from here
LinkedList.cpp:7: error: `Node<T>::_next' has incomplete type
LinkedList.cpp:5: error: declaration of `class Node<int>'
make[2]: *** [build/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/LinkedList.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make: *** [.build-impl] Error 2
```

I'm using NetBeans IDE. Could anybody give me some suggestion to improve it? Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Why not use `std::list`?  Is this for your own education?

Comment: C++ isn't Java. A class can't contain a member of its own type. There are no "generics" in C++. C++ really isn't the same as Java.

Comment: @Karthik, no, the class template's name injected into the scope, so `Node` with no template args refers to `Node<T>`. Kerrek has the right answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like when you do `Node<T> *node;` in the `LinkedList`, you need to also do the same in your `Node` class

```
template <class T>
class Node{
    T datum;
    Node<T> *_next;//template parameter
                   //also, need to make this a pointer and initialized in constructor
public:

//...
    void setNext(Node<T> next) //template parameter
    {
        _next = next;
    }
    Node<T> getNext() //template parameter
    {
        return _next;
    }
//...
};
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot. Actually, when I change it to a pointer type, it passes. Even if I don't add T after the Node! Anyway, Thanks!

Comment: In the class' own scope `Node` is equivalent to `Node<T>`

Comment: Yes, I found it does work without (as Jonathan Wakely points out in a comment). But I find it strange to not have them.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the syntax being wrong:

```
class Node{
T datum;
Node _next = NULL;
//....
```

you can't have a member of the same type as a member. You can use a pointer though:

```
template <class T>
class Node{
T datum;
Node<T>* _next;
```

and set it in the constructor (because `=NULL` wouldn't be legal there).

Related: [Why is a class allowed to have a static member of itself, but not a non-static member?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8517609/why-is-a-class-allowed-to-have-a-static-member-of-itself-but-not-a-non-static-m/8517644#8517644)

Comment: The `=NULL` would be valid in C++11

Answer (score 1):

Your `Node` class should contain a **pointer** to the next `Node`, not a `Node` directly. Here you've a recursive type which is impossible to handle for the compiler.

Another mistake is that you cannot initialize a member like this. You must do that in the constructor.

So, replace `Node _next = NULL;` by `Node *_next;` and initialize the pointer `_next` to `nullptr` in your constructor.

Comment: The compiler doesn't really matter. That's just a piece of software. What's important is that a type containing itself doesn't make *sense*.

Answer (score 1):

It might just be this line:

```
Node _next = NULL;
```

You really need that to be a pointer (`Node<T>* _next`). If a class contained an instance of its own type, then THAT instance would have its own instance of that type and so on *ad memorum exhaustum*.