# C++ error when creating an object of a class within the same class?

Tags: c++

Like Java and C#, can I create object of a class within the same class?

```
/* State.h */
class State{
  private:
    /*...*/
    State PrevState;
};
```

Error:

```
field 'PrevState' has incomplete type
```

Comment: You can't do that. The best you can do is `State *PrevState;`.

Comment: Such an object requires an infinite amount of memory and an infinite amount of time to initialize.

Comment: If you are familiar with C#, the code above is closer to `public struct State { public State nextState; }`. C++ is a language with value semantics, you have to explicitly request reference semantics (by means of pointers/references)

Comment: Related - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8517609/why-is-a-class-allowed-to-have-a-static-member-of-itself-but-not-a-non-static-m/8517644#8517644

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do this as written.  When you declare a variable as some type directly in a class (`Type variablename`) then the memory for the variable's allocation becomes part of its parent type's allocation.  Knowing this, it becomes clear why you can't do this: the allocation would expand recursively -- `PrevState` would need to allocate space for *it's* `PrevState` member, and so on forever.  Further, even if one could allocate an infinite amount of memory this way, the constructor calls would recurse infinitely.

You can, however, define a variable that is a reference or pointer to the containing type, either `State &` or `State *` (or some smart pointer type), since these types are of a fixed size (references are usually pointer-sized, and pointers will be either 4 or 8 bytes, depending on your architecture).

Answer (score 0):

You are mistaking `State PrevState` and `State* PrevState`. The cause of the problem is that you are assuming that C++ is *anything, at all* like Java and C#. It isn't. You need to spend some time brushing up your C++.

Answer (score 0):

> So why can you do this in C# and Java, but you cannot do this in C++?

In C++, objects can contain sub-objects. What this means is that the memory for the sub-object will be part of the object that contains it. However, in C# and Java, objects cannot have subobjects, when you do `State PrevState;` in one of those languages the memory resides somewhere else *outside* of the container and you are only holding a "reference" to the actual object within the class. To do that in C++, you would use a pointer or reference to the actual object.